# How to create a HTML form for payment autofill

Tags: html, autocomplete, payment, autofill

I'm looking to create a HTML form that will be used by the user to input his payment information (card, name, exp. date). I would like for the form to be autofill capable. Meaning, if the user have his or her cards added to the web browser, a drop down menu will pop for easy autofill.

The code of my form is bellow. Everything works but the Name and Last name part. I made this form after reading this link on [whatwg.org](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Autocomplete_Types). But still the *cc-name* is not working.

I looked on Google but the information that I found on this topic is all over the place and it seams there is no standard.

To make maters worst, if I look at other form from other sites that works. I see that they have even less appropriate information in theirs forms.

How this autofilling truly works?

```
<script>
  form.requestAutocomplete();
  event.preventDefault();
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Numer Karty</label>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input data-braintree-name="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="cc-number" type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000"  required="true" name="ccnumber" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imię i Nazwisko</label>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <input data-braintree-name="cardholder_name" class="form-control" autocomplete="cc-name" type="text" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" required="true" name="ccname">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ważność</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input data-braintree-name="expiration_month" class="form-control" autocomplete="cc-exp-month" type="text" placeholder="Miesiąc" required="true" name="ccexpmonth" inputmode="numeric">
      <input data-braintree-name="expiration_year" class="form-control" autocomplete="cc-exp-year" type="text" placeholder="Rok" required="true" name="ccexpyear" inputmode="numeric">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the autofill feature for browser will only work if you are behind a HTTPS connection. Smart, but this info is nowhere to be found.

I hope this help the next person :)